# How can I assign a one from -> Human | Animal | Alien | None as the type with @dataclass in Python 3.7.x+

Tags: python, types, python-dataclasses

I have the class initialled as follow

```
class Filter:
    ...
    # no need to assign types
    def get_type(self, type_name:str):
        if type_name == 'human':
            return Human()
        elif type_name == 'animal':
            return Animal()
        elif type_name == 'alien':
            return Alien()
        return None
    ...
```

and Filter.get_type() indicated in vscode similar to  `(method) get_type: (data: dict) -> Human | Animal | Alien | None` (vscode indication)

However, I am not sure how to assign the multiple optional types to my variable like

```
import Filter

my_type: ??? = Filter.get_type()
```

By adding the type to `my_type`, the auto completion will recognize the sub-classes and variables in Human, Animal, and Alien (or bypass None)

How can I assign multiple types from the list `[Human, Animal, Alien]`  to my_type?

Comment: um, `Human | Animal | Alien | None`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the question is for python 3.7.x, not 3.10

Comment: @bottledmind FWIW the syntax with the `|` operator can actually be made to work in python 3.7 using a `from __future__ import annotations` import

Comment: ```Human | Animal | Alien | None```  is the indication from vscode, I am not sure if it is valid syntax in python at all; but I believe the way to add multiple type options would be the same between 3.7.x ~ 3.10.x

Comment: @jbl Its only valid syntax in 3.10 when is when the [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0604/) for the new Union operator was introduced. In previous python versions, using the `__future__` import effectively wraps the annotation in a string, so for example `A | B` in 3.10 becomes `'A | B'` in previous versions - note the single quotes around the annotation, indicating that it's now a string value.

Answer (score 2):

**Edited**. Hope this time it is what you meant

```
from typing import Union

class Filter:
    ...
    def get_type(self, type_name:str) -> Union[Human, Animal, Alien, None]:
        if type_name == 'human':
            return Human()
        elif type_name == 'animal':
            return Animal()
        elif type_name == 'alien':
            return Alien()
        return None
    ...

my_type: Union[Human, Animal, Alien, None] = Filter.get_type()
```

Comment: Union is the best option for now across 3.7~3.11 and you can customize the types directly without importing in 3.11

Answer (score 0):

Try this, that uses the concept of `Literal` in 3.8 to make type 'sets', plus uses `Optional` to indicate when `None` may be a valid type (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html):

```py
from typing import Literal, Optional

Filter_Types: Literal[Human, Animal, Alien]

class Filter:

    def get_type(self, type_name: str) -> Optional[Filter_Types]:
        ...
```